# SQL Server Stored Procedure Caching Old Results Even After Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, caching, stored-procedures

I have a weird issue I've never ran into before.  I have a stored procedure that joins a bunch of data.  When I do an update on a table that is found in one of the joins it doesnt update, until say 20-30 seconds later, or not at all.  I see the value updated in the actual table, but the stored procedure has the old value.  I didnt think stored procedures could cache like this, or delay like this.  Where should I look to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try aliasing all of your tables and using the correct alias in the SELECT portion of your query.ff

Comment: I am modifying data from Entity Framework which I can see updated in SQL management studio.

Comment: Try putting a select statement in your stored procedure that will select just the data from the data table in question to see if it has what you think it should.  This will eliminate any confusion about the JOIN in your actual query.

Comment: I create a new SP just like the other and added the select to grab the actual row inside that SP.  The new Select shows the correct data, but SP select doesnt.

Comment: If you have the same column in multiple tables used in your query, maybe you are missing the correct table alias in the SELECT portion of your query.

Comment: Yep I believe it is this: COALESCE(divisionPoolBracket.Name, divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Name).  I switched it and it looks to be working.  I have a background service processing the other part which eventually gets updated, hence the delay haha.  Geez, if you update your answer to use an alias in the SQL Ill mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is some caching possibly of the old query plan for the previous version of the stored procedure. It seems like a bug in SQL Server. After a short period of time, it seems to update it but yes - pretty sure it's a bug.

Source: using SSMS on SQL Server 2012 -> 2017 for large data management